# Laravel - Getting values of select menu to input into database

Tags: php, html, laravel

Hi so I'm trying to change my forms for creating an appointment, I currently have a foreach loop for radio buttons and it works but ofcourse it doesn't look great. So i'm trying to instead use a select menu so it look better, but when I try submit my new form it tells me the doctor field must be selected, so it's not getting the actual value of what's selected.

addappointmentform.blade (OLD VERSION as stated above this works but looks bad)

```
    <fieldset>
<legend>Select the Doctor</legend>
@foreach($doctors as $doctor)
    <div>
        <label for="dirBtn{{$doctor->id}}">
        <input id="dirBtn{{$doctor->id}}" type="radio" name="doctor" value="{{$doctor->id}}">Dr
        {{$doctor->surname}}
        </label>
    </div>
@endforeach
</fieldset>
```

addappointmentform.blade(NEW VERSION, this is what i'm trying to get working)

```
    <fieldset>
<select name="doctorsSelect">
    <option selected disabled>Please select a Doctor</option>
    @foreach($doctors as $doctor)


                <option value="{{ $doctor->id }}"
                name="doctor" input id="dirBtn{{$doctor->id}}" value="{{$doctor->id}}">
                Dr {{$doctor->surname}}</option>


    @endforeach
</select>
    </fieldset>
```

AppointmentController

```
function addAppointmentDatabase(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'time' => 'required|',
            'date' => 'required|min:10|max:10|filled',
            'doctor' => 'required',
            'user' => 'required',
        ]);
        //create a appointment
        $appointment = new Appointment();
        $appointment->time=$request->time;
        $appointment->date=$request->date;


        //assign doctor to appointment
        $doctor = Doctor::find($request->doctor);
        $appointment->doctor()->associate($doctor);

        $user = User::find($request->user);
        $appointment->user()->associate($user);

        //save the appointment
        $appointment->save();


        return redirect('all');
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need an `id` for the `option`, Also your `select` needs to have the `name` of the previous `input`.

Something like this:

```
<fieldset>
    <select name="doctor">
        <option selected disabled>Please select a Doctor</option>
        @foreach($doctors as $doctor)
            <option value="{{$doctor->id}}">Dr {{$doctor->surname}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Your select name is doctorsSelect, change it to doctor:

`<select name="doctor">`